# WP_Query args to show posts from specific custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy for my posts called "Regions." And I have tagged 2 posts with these regions. What I would like to do is list out any post that is tagged with a region, but for some reason it's not working. Here's my function to register the custom taxonomy:

```
function region_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Regions' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Regions' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Region' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Region:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Region' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Region' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Region' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Region Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Regions' )
    );

    register_taxonomy('regions',array('post'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'region' )
    ));

}

add_action('init', 'region_taxonomy', 0);
```

And here's the `WP_Query` from my page template:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'regions'
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?> 
    <p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p> 
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Unfortunately this is returning no posts even though I have 2 posts tagged with a Region. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy query doesn't work without `terms` parameter. So you have to first query all the **regions** term then assign term ids to taxonomy query.

Here's the solution -

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'regions',
    'fields'   => 'id=>slug',
) );

$args = array( 
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'regions',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array_keys( $terms ),
        ),
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>';
}
```

Btw, you shouldn't use `wp_reset_query()` it's costly and should be used with `query_posts()` only instead use `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Great thank you, and thank you for the additional tip regarding resetting the query!

Comment: Great to see that you already solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently only specifying the `taxonomy` is not enough, I was able to solve my issue like this:

```
<?php
    $regions_terms = get_terms('regions');
    $regions = array();
    foreach ($regions_terms as $regions_term) {
        $regions[] = $regions_term->slug;
    }
    $args = array( 
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'tax_query' => array(
           array(
              'taxonomy' => 'regions',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => $regions
           )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => '3'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```